# API for finding load time of a web page

Tags: java, web-applications, html

Is there any API to find out the load time of a web page?What are the other ways to find out the load time of a web page?

Answer (score 0):

refer http://www.hashemian.com/tools/page-load-time.htm

Here's the simple JavaScript Web page load time code (copy and paste at the top of Web page):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
PLT_DisplayFormat = "Your connection took %%S%% seconds to load this page.";
PLT_BackColor = "palegreen";
PLT_ForeColor = "navy";
PLT_FontPix = "12";
PLT_DisplayElementID = "display_here";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.hashemian.com/js/PageLoadTime.js"></script>
```

Example: The line below is coded as: .

`Your connection took 8.486 seconds to load this page.`

Comment: Thank u ..but how to extract the load time value and store it in a database...my problem is wen i click a url i should store the loadtime in a database...

Comment: check the code of the PageLoadTime.js file  PLT_DisplayFormat = PLT_DisplayFormat.replace(/%%S%%/g, ((new Date() - dt)/1000)); this code helps you .